# Pegar valor de Variável JS e passar para o PHP e enviar por URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo.
Quero saber se há como enviar através da URL uma variável que foi passada do JS para o PHP.A intensão do código é passar a variável apos clicar no botão.

OBS.:O usuário vai ser direcionado para está pagina descrita no link

```
<html>
   <head>
   
  <title>Passar Variável Javascript para PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var variaveljs = 'Mauricio Programador';
  </script>
   </head>

  <body>
   
  <?php
     $nome="<script>
     $(function() {
         $('#botao').click(function () {

             document.write(variaveljs);
         });
     });</script>";


       ?>

  <div id="botao">
    <?php
     echo " <a href='pagina2.php?valor='.$nome>Botão</a>";
     ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por quê você precisa passar uma variável JS para o PHP para depois gerar um link no mesmo documento do JS com a variável? Não basta só utilizar JS?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem sua questão, você pode passar por get utilizando o jquery:

$.get( "pagina2.php", { valor: variaveljs } );

Comment: @MárcioCristian Nunca usei esse forma.Se eu passar os dados para a  "pagina2" e logo em seguida for direcionado pra ela ,ainda terei acesso aos dados ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Bem, necessito passar os valores da pagina 1 para a pagina 2 e ser redirecionado de pg1 para a p2 e ter acesso aos dados na p2 para manipular.Posso fazer isso só com o JS.Tentei usar o ajax mas ($.AJAX();) mas percebi que não funciona pois quando sou direcionado para p2 ,nao tenho acesso aos dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você nem precisa de PHP para isso. Se o valor já está na página que haverá o link, basta utilizar JS apenas.

Exemplo simples:

```js
const variavel = "SOpt";
const link = document.getElementById('link');

link.href += variavel;
```

```html
<a id="link" href="pagina.php?valor=">Link</a>
```

Isso irá gerar o link `pagina.php?valor=SOpt`.

Comment: Como eu posso fazer isso com jquery? e o valor ir alternando com click?
Estou usando esse codigo abaixo
$('.os').on('click', function(){

var escolha = $(this).attr('name');
$('#o').html(escolha);

quando clico em uma imagem com a classe .cs ele pega o valor no atributo name e vai alternando no clique. Com o seu estou usando assim var escolha = $(this).attr('name');
link.href += escolha; e o valor fica acumulando em vez de alternar